# Azure APIM pricing tiers and Virtual Networks

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-api-management

From the [Azure API management pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/) I see that Virtual Networks aren't supported besides the Developer and Premium tiers.

Currently with my developer tier subscription when configuring the VN of an APIM I can choose between "off", "External" and "Internal". With the other tiers, can I still use an External VN or no VN at all?

When I try to connect a kubernetes cluster/VM to the APIM, I have to configure the APIM with an external VN. So if that's not possible with the other subscription tiers, is it still possible to connect to a kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VNET Support (and hence the options) are available only in the Developer and Premium Tiers.

You can still use APIM by routing requests from APIM to the [AKS load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard) using a [static IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip) and overriding the `Host` header as required. If possible, you could also use [Azure Application Gateway as an ingress controller](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) too.

**When taking the load balancer approach,** you could setup a [Network Security Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview) to allow traffic only from APIM (and any other IPs/Services) to your AKS nodes.

**When taking the Application Gateway approach,** you could setup [IP restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-overview#allow-application-gateway-access-to-a-few-source-ips) to APIM.

You should be able to setup a similar source IP rule on your own ingress controller too instead of an NSG rule I suppose.